# Bigquery - Insert new data row into table by python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I read many documents about google bigquery-python, but I can't understand how to manage bigquery data by python code.

At first, I make a new table as below.

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials = credentials)

project_id = 'my_project'
dataset_id = 'my_dataset'
table_id = 'my_table'

project_ref = {'projectId': project_id}
dataset_ref = {'datasetId': dataset_id,
               'projectId': project_id}
table_ref = {'tableId': table_id,
             'datasetId': dataset_id,
             'projectId': project_id}

dataset = {'datasetReference': dataset_ref}
table = {'tableReference': table_ref}
table['schema'] = {'fields': [
    {'name': 'id', 'type': 'string'},
...
]}

table = service.tables().insert(body = table, **dataset_ref).execute()
```

And then I want to insert a data into this table, so I tried to do like below.

```
fetch_list = []
patch = {'key': 'value'}
fetch_list.append(patch)

table = service.tables().patch(body = fetch_list, **table_ref).execute()
```

But nothing happened.

How can I update new data into bigquery table?

Please show me some example codes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> EDIT Nov 2018:

The answer of this question is outdated already as the google cloud client has evolved considerably since this last post.

The official docs contains all information needed already; [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) you can find everything needed for streaming insert and [this one](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) has a complete overview of all methods available so far (you'll also find Python code examples on each page and each method).

> Original Answer:

There are a few different ways that you can use to insert data to BQ.

For a deeper understanding of how the python-api works, here's everything you'll need: [bq-python-api](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/) (at first the docs are somewhat scary but after you get a hang of it it's rather quite simple).

There are 2 main methods that I use to insert data to BQ. The first one is [data streaming](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tabledata.html#insertAll) and it's supposed to be used when you can insert row by row in a real time fashion. Code example:

```
import uuid
def stream_data(self, table, data, schema):
    # first checks if table already exists. If it doesn't, then create it
    r = self.service.tables().list(projectId=your_project_id,
                                     datasetId=your_dataset_id).execute()
    table_exists = [row['tableReference']['tableId'] for row in
                    r['tables'] if
                    row['tableReference']['tableId'] == table]
    if not table_exists:
        body = {
            'tableReference': {
                'tableId': table,
                'projectId': your_project_id,
                'datasetId': your_dataset_id
            },
            'schema': schema
        }
        self.service.tables().insert(projectId=your_project_id,
                                     datasetId=your_dataset_id,
                                     body=body).execute()

    # with table created, now we can stream the data
    # to do so we'll use the tabledata().insertall() function.
    body = {
        'rows': [
            {
                'json': data,
                'insertId': str(uuid.uuid4())
            }
        ]
    }
    self.service.tabledata().insertAll(projectId=your_project_id),
                                       datasetId=your_dataset_id,
                                       tableId=table,
                                         body=body).execute(num_retries=5)
```

Here my `self.service` is correspondent to your `service` object.

An example of input `data` that we have in our project:

```
data = {u'days_validated': '20', u'days_trained': '80', u'navigated_score': '1', u'description': 'First trial of top seller alg. No filter nor any condition is applied. Skus not present in train count as rank=0.5', u'init_cv_date': '2016-03-06', u'metric': 'rank', u'unix_date': '1461610020241117', u'purchased_score': '10', u'result': '0.32677139316724546', u'date': '2016-04-25', u'carted_score': '3', u'end_cv_date': '2016-03-25'}
```

And its correspondent `schema`:

```
schema = {u'fields': [{u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'unix_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'init_cv_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'end_cv_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'days_trained', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'days_validated', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'navigated_score', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'carted_score', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'purchased_score', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'description', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'metric', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'FLOAT', u'name': u'result', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}
```

The other way to insert data is to use the [job insert](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) function. As you can see in the documentation, it accepts several sources for your data. I have an example of how you can do so by loading the results of a query into another table:

```
def create_table_from_query(self,
                            query,
                            dest_table,
                            how):
    body = {
        'configuration': {
            'query': {
                'destinationTable': {
                    'projectId': your_project_id,
                    'tableId': dest_table,
                    'datasetId': your_dataset_id
                },
                'writeDisposition': how,
                'query': query,
            },
        }
    }

    response = self.connector.jobs().insert(projectId=self._project_id,
                                            body=body).execute()
    self.wait_job_completion(response['jobReference']['jobId'])

def wait_job_completion(self, job_id):
    while True:
        response = self.connector.jobs().get(projectId=self._project_id,
                                             jobId=job_id).execute()
        if response['status']['state'] == 'DONE':
            return
```

The `how` input accepts the available options for this field in the documentation (such as "WRITE_TRUNCATE", or "WRITE_APPEND").

You can load the data from a csv file for instance, in this case, the `configuration` variable would be defined something along the lines:

```
"configuration": {
  "load": {
    "fieldDelimiter": "\t"
    "sourceFormat": "CSV"
    "destinationTable": {
      "projectId": your_project_id,
      "tableId": table_id,
      "datasetId": your_dataset_id
    },
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    "schema": schema,
    "sourceUris": file_location_in_google_cloud_storage
  },
}
```

(Using as example a csv file delimited by tabs. It could be a json file as well, the documentation will walk you through the available options).

Running jobs() require some time for it to complete (that's why we created the `wait_job_completion` method). It should be cheaper though as compared to real time streaming.

Any questions let us know,

Comment: Hi from the documentation I only see you can upload CSV or Query results to table, but I'm wondering how can I append a row (python list) to a table using insert() method?

Comment: Maybe this one will help you: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/table.html#Table.insert_data. The python google client has evolved a lot since I last posted this answer, it might be worth learning to use it as well: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html
Notice that in your case it might be better to use the 'live stream' method as you just want to insert a few lists to BQ.

Comment: Links above are broken @WillianFuks

Comment: @skeller88 you're right. Here's the correct link for live stream: https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.insert_data. For reading a CSV from storage, here's an example: https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#inserting-data-asynchronous. I'll update my answer with these links. Thanks for the message :)

Comment: @WillianFuks Both, links above and the ones on the answer are broken

Comment: @AndrésNavarro Thanks for the warning, already fixed the links in my answer to the official gcp docs now :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery), the easiest way to just insert a couple of rows is the following:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of table to append to.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table"

rows_to_insert = [
    {"full_name": "Phred Phlyntstone", "age": 32},
    {"full_name": "Wylma Phlyntstone", "age": 29},
]

errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

Comment: 403 POST: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Streaming insert is not allowed in the free tier